# How to change the Y axis range of a matplotlib graph?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am writing a code to get a graph:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#importing the excel sheet with elements, mass and atomic number
x=pd.read_excel('Elements.xlsx')
#converting atomic number column to a list
Z=x['Z'].tolist()
#converting mass column to another list
A=x['A'].tolist()
#giving the constants some value
a1,a2,a3=14.1,13,0.595
#finding binding energy per nucleon of each element using liquid drop model
bepn=[]
for i in range(0,118):
    y=a1-(a2/(A[i])**(1/3))-(a3*Z[i]*(Z[i]-1)/(A[i])**(4/3))
    bepn.append(y)
#plotting the graph
plt.plot(A,bepn)
plt.xlabel("Atomic mass")
plt.ylabel("Binding energy per nucleon")
plt.show
```

The obtained graph shows y axis with a range from -50 to 10. But I want the y axis to be from 0 to 9. What should I change in the code to do that?

Comment: It seems to me it's not a problem with matplotlib, it's your methodology for computing the binding energy.  I suggest you to close this question and ask a new one, possibly on the physics or chemistry SE.

Answer (score 1):

You should try this :

```
plt.ylim(0, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice `y` before plotting it on the graph, but you need to do this with `x` too.

If the `y` values are all integers, you can do the following:

```
plt.plot(A[50:],bepn[50:])
```